# Low TPS using Virtualbox + Ubuntu + Nginx + PHP-FPM + Silex

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php, silex

I am trying to understand why I get such a low TPS rate on my development environment.

I am using the following:

- Mac OS X Mavericks
- VirtualBox
- Ubuntu 14.04
- Nginx
- PHP5-FPM
- Silex

I did not tweak the configuration much, just nginx to enable the silex front controller.

Using JMeter, I am testing how many requests per second this environment can handle and what I am seeing so far is ~14 transaction per seconds. The endpoint that I am hitting is a simple hello world spitting a hardcoded json response.

At first I thought nginx or php was not accepting concurrent connections but it looks like it is enabled by default.

If I run one single thread, each requests takes 70ms or so, if I run 10 threads, each takes close to a second, and so on. No matter how many threads I have, the throughput is 13/14 tps. While I run this, `top` shows that all 5 php5-fpm processes take approximately 20% of the CPU each.

Am I doing something wrong or is this expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, it's the Virtualbox share that's extremely slow. Moving the code to a folder on the VM resulted in a 15 fold TPS increase.